# how to use iptables to forward requests on port 80 to another port based on url

Tags: redirect, iptables, portforwarding

I'm currently forwarding all requests on port 80 to the ports my web server is listening on. I'm trying to see if it's possible to forward the requests on port 80 based on a condition. The condition being which url the user is attempting to access... since I have multiple domains forwarding to the same web server. This will allow me to setup multiple ssl enabled listeners, each on a different port, to serve secure content for it's domain. Thx ahead of time for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use iptables for this, because iptables works on a much lower level than the HTTP application level (for the most part).

Also, if you are trying to accomplish "virtual hosting" for SSL and serve different certificates based on the hostname, be aware that the HTTP Host header is only sent after a successful HTTPS negotiation. There's a workaround called SNI. So what you should look for is a web server or reverse proxy that supports SNI.